# UIPageViewController Xamarin

Tags: c#, xamarin.ios

I need to implement a simple UIPageViewController using Xamarin in Visual Studio 2017 for mac.

As the documentation says in https://developer.xamarin.com/api/type/MonoTouch.UIKit.UIPageViewController/ I need to connect the previous and next views, using `UIPageViewControllerDataSource.GetNextViewController` and `UIPageViewControllerDataSource.GetPreviousViewController` from the `UIPageViewControllerDataSource` delegate, but I'm not clear where should I do that, nor I see any where to do that using the storyboard designer.

The idea to use the UIPageViewController is to add a quick tutorial of 4 pages before advancing to another View, at the last view of the UIPageViewController there would be a button that calls the segway to the next page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add a `UIPageViewController` in the Storyboard. Configure the style in the Properties window => Widget(Navigation, Transition Style, Spine Location).

Then you can add the `DataSource` in the corresponding CS file. Add the firstly shown UIViewController using: `SetViewControllers(new UIViewController[] { viewController }, UIPageViewControllerNavigationDirection.Forward, true, null);`. Please notice that when you set the `Spine Location` to `Mid`, this array should contain at least two `UIViewControllers`. If not, add just one.

> but I'm not clear where should I do that, nor I see any where to do
>   that using the storyboard designer.

When you want to navigate to the next page, the event `GetNextViewController()` will fire(i.e. first page - second page). And you should return which Controller will show in this event. Also `GetPreviousViewController()` means which Controller you want to show when navigate back. Here is my sample:

```
public class MyPageViewDataSource : UIPageViewControllerDataSource
{

    List<UIViewController> pageList;
    public MyPageViewDataSource(List<UIViewController> pages)
    {
        pageList = pages;
    }

    public override UIViewController GetNextViewController(UIPageViewController pageViewController, UIViewController referenceViewController)
    {           
        var index = pageList.IndexOf(referenceViewController);
        if (index < pageList.Count - 1)
        {
            return pageList[++index];
        }
        else
        {
            //when navigate to the last page, return null to disable navigate to next.
            return null;
        }
    }

    public override UIViewController GetPreviousViewController(UIPageViewController pageViewController, UIViewController referenceViewController)
    {
        var index = pageList.IndexOf(referenceViewController);
        if (index == 0)
        {
            //when navigate to the first page, return null to disable navigate to previous.
            return null;
        }
        else
        {
            return pageList[index - 1];
        }
    }
}
```

At last set your `UIPageViewController`'s DataSource to this:`DataSource = new MyPageViewDataSource(pageList);`

Comment: How can I create the `pageList` object? I tryied adding names to the views but I can't reference them.

Comment: pageList is a UIViewController list. You can construct a new UIViewController with only one image in it. Then init the list with your ViewControllers.

Comment: At last I made it work! But there is no indicator in the bottom of the Page I'm going through. How can I add a Page indicator?

Comment: That’s another control called UIPageControl.

Comment: I saw it, but I don't know how and where to add it

Comment: @Gino can u post ur working code as another answer to the question ?

Comment: At the very end we implemented iCarousel for Xamarin. It is a binding for the iCarousel for swift